# Custom metadata type in Stub api

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-metadata, stubapi

I am using trying to stub my class, but I have `get` and `set` for custom metadata. I know that I cannot stub get and set. Is there exist any design for using it in stub? Or I must just hardcode it and create a list (or something else) with custom metadata objects? Google didn't help find the answer

Sorry have problems with net and cannot update. Here is my get and set for  custom metadata

```
@testVisible  List<Configuration__mdt> configuration{

    get{
        if(configuration == NULL){
            configuration = [SELECT Object__c, queryCondition__c FROM Configuration__mdt];
        }
        return configuration;
    }
    set;
}
@testVisible  List<ConfigFields__mdt> configFields{
    get{
        if(configFields == NULL){
            configFields = [SELECT fieldName__c FROM         ConfigFields__mdt];
        }
        return configFields;
    }
    set;
}
```

Comment: Custom Metadata can be queried from Org in test class even with `SeeAllData=false`. So you may not need a stub api for that.

Comment: can you provide your code, which you are trying to stub ? `{get;set;}` properties can always be replaced with getter and setter method.

Comment: Hi. Please add samples of your code because it is not clear what you mean by "get and set" for custom metadata. Do you mean use of metadata API? Do you mean use of get Instance? Please [edit] to add details (do not reply in a comment).

Comment: BTW a typical option is to ensure you provide a separate class that provides the API through which you update and retrieve custom metadata type records then stub that class. You can create in-memory custom metadata type records via `JSON.deserialize` without any restriction.

Comment: @PhilW thanks. I think i understand. Added code if needed.

Comment: @PhilW actually i dont get  that part 'separate class that provides the API through which you update and retrieve custom metadata type records'. Can u give any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, you can replace `get` and `set` properties (as it is not possible to mock properties with `Stub API`) with the getter and the setter method, and you can mock them.

```
private List<Configuration__mdt> configuration;
private List<ConfigFields__mdt> configFields;

public List<Configuration__mdt> getConfiguration(){
    if(configuration == NULL){
        configuration = [SELECT Object__c, queryCondition__c FROM Configuration__mdt];
    }
    return configuration;
}

public void setConfiguration(List<ConfigFields__mdt> configuration){
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

public List<ConfigFields__mdt> getConfigFields(){
    if(configFields == NULL){
        configFields = [SELECT fieldName__c FROM ConfigFields__mdt];
    }
    return configFields;
}

public void setConfigFields(List<ConfigFields__mdt> configFields){
    this.configFields = configFields;
}
```

Comment: So i  must just  create list of mdt in  test class and pass to setConfigFields/setConfiguration?  Thanks.

Comment: and you are mocking with those lists `getConfiguration` and `getConfigFields` methods

Comment: Got it. I thought about another method but no clues.